# JavaScript not showing any alert dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>BD Home page</title>    
        <style>
            body { background-color:red; }
            p { background-color:yellow; }
            div { background-color:green; }
        </style>    
    </head>    
    <body>
        <script>
            function mf() {
                Var x = new Date();
                alert("Today is: " + x);
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="mf()">Click</button>
        <div>Hellllllooooo</div>
        <p>Hello this is html</p>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello I am a beginner programmer. In the error code it says mf is not defined on line 1:1, cannot understand that. Is it important to enclose an alert dialog box under a function?

Comment: `Var` needs to be lowercase as `var`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks :) now its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `var` instead of `Var`. Javascript `var` keyword must be simple letters

Answer (score -1):

Remove Var before the x or replace it by var ("v" lowercase).

Comment: dupe of @DININDU's answer